# How to search and replace text in all php-files in a directory and it's subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, find, ls

I am looking for a shell script that recursively traverses all `.php` files in a directory and performs a search & replace of a particular text pattern.

The search pattern is quite long ( > 5000 characters) so it might be saved in another textfile for convenience. Also it contains forward slash characters.

edit:
 i think i figured out the first part:

```
find . -name "*.php"
```

but then how do i search & replace in those files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done easily with a good combination of sed and xargs.

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 echo
```

will show you the power of xargs.

After that, on a sample file, you can test the regexp, with an inplace change (-i) or a backup change (-i.bak). You can also use an other character to replace '/' if your pattern/replacement already have one.

At the end, it should looks like :

```
pattern=`cat /path/to/pattern`; replacement=`cat /path/to/replacement`
find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s|$pattern|$replacement|g"
```

Comment: ok thank you! same question here: how would i load the search pattern from a file?

Comment: something like this, maybe ? pattern=`cat /path/to/pattern`; replacement=`cat /path/to/replacement`; find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s/$pattern/$replacement/g"

Comment: thank you! the only problem remaining is that the pattern contains forward slashes which seem to be problematic in the regexp

Comment: you can use an other character than '/' in sed. For instance, `sed -i -e "|$pattern|$replacement|g` works well

Comment: thank you! now it runs without errors but it doesnt seem to replace anything. i guess the search pattern is not found. (although it is there). the search pattern contains all kind of characters including tabs, spaces, $, <, > etc. could that be the problem?

Comment: $ is used by bash for variables. you'll need to escape it with a '\'.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s/$(cat /path/to/pattern.txt)/$(cat /path/to/replacement.txt)/g" {} \;
```

where `pattern` is the pattern to search for and `replacement` is the text to replace it with.

The `-i` option for `sed` edits the files "in place". If you want to create a backup of the file before you edit it, use `-i'.bak'`.

Comment: thanks! how would i get pattern and replacement from a file?

Comment: @clamp Replace the argument to `sed` by `"s/$(cat /path/to/pattern.txt)/$(cat /path/to/replacement.txt)/g"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/originalString/targetString/g' `find . -name '*' -type f`
```

Comment: Can you explain this?