# Removing a long string from php files - using grep and sed?

Tags: linux, grep, sed, php, tr

I have encountered some malware on my Linux server, and am trying to remove it from many php files.

I've tried endlessly with grep | sed and grep | tr and couldn't even erase a simple text string, getting different errors.

When trying:

```
grep -l '@error' * | xargs -0 sed -i 's/error/nothing/g'
```

I receive an error message:

> can't read *filename*.php

Using Terminal on Mac - maybe it's an OSX syntax problem?

My final task is to delete a long string of code from all the files - one that includes some $,!,?,<,>,\," symbols - will I need to backslash them?

Comment: It is generally much safer to restore from backup or from your source control repository. You don't have those available?

Comment: @Mat - thanks, but it's too many backups to run, I also have the specific code I'm need to remove.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search and replace text in all php-files in a directory and it's subdirectories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-all-php-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirec)

Comment: Why make backups if you can't / won't use them? Better rethink your backup *and restore* strategies. Best practice is a full restore when a server was compromised. Also, backups are a perfect way to find out what's changed since a previous date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restore from backup or source control as [@Mat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5842/mat) suggested because otherwise you cannot be 100% sure you cleaned up everything.

The problem with your command is the `-0` flag for `xargs`, because that way `xargs` is expecting null-terminated arguments, which does not work with the output of `grep -l`. Just drop the `-0` and it will work, as long as the file names don't have white spaces in them.

```
grep -l '@error' * | xargs sed -i 's/error/nothing/g'
```

Comment: Thanks. This works - the '-0' was the catch here.
BTW - I am trying to save a log file with the list of files in which the replacement was made.
Any tips on how to do that?  When I save the grep results to a file they are not piped to the xargs.

Thank you Janos and community!

Comment: Sure!`grep -l '@error' * | tee list.log | xargs sed -i 's/error/nothing/g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l @error * | xargs sed -i s/error/test/g
```

will work.