# Search and replace login string in all .php files in directory when filenames contain spaces

Tags: sed, xargs

I changed my password and username for mySQL and I need to replace the connection string in all of my PHP scripts accordingly.

I am having trouble with the command because many of my php file names contain spaces.

What can I change to make this command work without having "No such file or directory" errors?

Here is the command I am using:

```
pattern='mysql_connect("localhost", "olduser", "oldpwd")'
replacement='mysql_connect("localhost", "newuser", "newpwd")'
find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e 's|$pattern|$replacement|g'
```

I am unfamiliar with xargs and sed and I copied this code from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-all-php-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirec) answer to a similar question.

(I think I will put the mysql_connect statement into a php include file and only change it in one place next time.)

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using BASH

Comment: I know this is going to be something simple, but I'm old and I can't remember. Heh.

Comment: Something like ${i##*}  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `NULL byte` and double quotes :

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 |
    xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e "s|$pattern|$replacement|g"
```

Or with a simple *for loop*:

```
for p in *php; do
    sed -i -e "s|$pattern|$replacement|g" "$p"
done
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple.  Thanks!  I'll accept your answer so you get the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find success by replacing the values like so:

`find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e 's/\"olduser\", \"oldpwd\"/\"newuser\", \"newpwd\"/g'`